# Windows setting to turn off global indicator state for caps, nums, and scroll lock button lights

Tags: windows-10, window

I have multiple keyboards plugged into my computer (for a multi user program). When I press the caps lock key on one the indicator light on all them turns on. I would like to turn off that functionality and make the indicator lights per keyboard. I understand most programs will not respect the per keyboard caps lock state (same for nums lock and scroll lock), but I am writing a program that will query the indicator light state from each keyboard on program startup (and new device connected) and handle the states for each itself.

So, does a windows setting exist that I can set to prevent a global indicator light state between all keyboards?

Comment: Not possible...